# Is it possible to use the name of a Typescript interface as a key in a generic type?

Tags: typescript, generics, typing

I would like to create a generic type that uses the *name* of the type parameter as a key in the resultant type. There is no need for such a type to exist in the transpiled JavaScript. It only needs to work for the purpose of type enforcement for the TypeScript source.

I first tried something like this...

```
export type Wrapped<T> = {
    `${T}`: T;
};
```

...and this...

```
export type Wrapped<T> = {
    [nameof T]: T;
};
```

but these aren't valid.

For example...

```js
interface MyInterface {
    text: string;
}

const instance: MyInterface = { 'text': 'Hello!' };
const wrappedInstance: Wrapped<MyInterface> = { 'MyInterface': { 'text': 'World!' } };
```

Is TypeScript capable of creating such a type?

Answer (score 1):

This is simply not possible on the current version of Typescript (4.6). The *name* of a type simply cannot be used as a type of any sort.

Whatever you are doing, you'll need to find another way.

Comment: A straightforward, clear answer. Thank you.